# West wall of house in Phoenix is cinder block with no insulation. How can I insulate it?

Tags: insulation, cinderblock

A north/south situated single level townhome in Phoenix has a west facing wall that bakes in the summer heat.  It's about 10' tall.  The interior walls are 8'.  Both bedrooms and bathrooms are situated along this wall.  The finish is 1/2" drywall.  The only thing between the drywall and the block wall is a 3/4" gap furred out by 3/4" thick wood strips at 16" on center.

**Modifying the exterior is not an option** as the HOA is responsible for all landscaping, so the **only thing that I can do is something between the cinder block and the finished wall**, or spray-in foam to fill the cinder blocks (which I've read isn't optimal for the cost.)

What is the best course of action to reduce the radiant heat inside?

[image: Model of the home]

Comment: can you grow shrubs in front or vines on the outside wall? That would help a lot. The army uses cammo netting to breakup the shadow over tents; very effective, but unlikely to be your aesthetic; plants accomplish the same thing while looking nice.

Comment: And some shrubs / small trees loose leaves in winter allowing the solar energy through to the wall - passive solar design...

Comment: @dandavis answers down below!

Comment: The problem with shrubs next to a house is that some shrubs over time can grow much larger than needed and can develop large roots which grow under a slab foundation and can disturb drains if there are drains near the exterior wall. These shrubs can also excessively dry out the soil u der the foundation by transpiration.

Comment: In which case, @JimStewart one should consult with a local landscape place to get recommendations for A) what kind of shrubs to plant, B) how far away from the house to plant 'em, and C) watering schedules to ensure they survive and don't cause damage to the property.

Comment: How far is it from the west wall of the house to the west property line? How far is it from the west property line to the east wall of the neighboring house?

Comment: What color is the wall?

Comment: No exterior modifications can be made.  The only modifications that can be done are inside the building.

Comment: @JonGriffith -- is this really the only wall in this place with this problem? If I were in your shoes, I'd make a business case to the HOA that these uninsulated walls are costing everyone who has to put up with them good money every day they stay uninsulated, vs folks getting together and paying once to have them fixed for good.

Comment: The HOA is not responsible for the interior.  They are only responsible for the block wall.  Everything inside of the block walls is the owner's responsibility.